# Print test summary to console in JUnit 5

Tags: java, testing, kotlin, junit, junit5

Is it possible in JUnit 5 to print a test summary at the end of all tests to the console?

It should contain a list of the tests that have failed, and a list of the ones that were successful.

Comment: How are you launching your tests?

Comment: @Héctor I am using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

try `gradle test -i`
this will print test cases with result and the final output result.

Comment: Gradle only writes `56 tests completed, 1 failed, 3 skipped`.
However, I want a summary with the name of the tests.